# Select2 Show Currently Searched Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2

I'm using [Selec2](https://select2.github.io/) framework to do this with ajax call, i'm successfully implement this in my project but why when enter value to search it's showing current search value as selectable option, even when no result, i wan't to hide this. Any suggestion? thanks

Showing curent search value and it's selectable:
[image]

Even when no result:
[image]

HTML:

```
<select style='width:100%;' id='select-employee'></select>
```

JS:

```
$("#select-employee").select2({
    theme: "bootstrap",
    placeholder: "Select employee...",
    minimumInputLength: 1,
    tags: [],
    ajax: {
        url: "getEmployee.php",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        delay: 250,
        data: function(params) {
            return {
                term: params.term,
                page: params.page
            };
        },
        processResults: function(data, params) {
            params.page = params.page || 0;
            return {
                results: data.items,
                pagination: {
                    more: (data.page == "1" ? true : false)
                }
            };
        },
        cache: true
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi it's because you have to fill tags to false, try to change `[]` to `false`

```
$("#select-employee").select2({
  theme: "bootstrap",
  placeholder: "Select employee...",
  minimumInputLength: 1,
  tags: false,
  ajax: {
    url: "getEmployee.php",
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    delay: 250,
    data: function(params) {
        return {
            term: params.term,
            page: params.page
        };
    },
    processResults: function(data, params) {
        params.page = params.page || 0;
        return {
            results: data.items,
            pagination: {
                more: (data.page == "1" ? true : false)
            }
        };
    },
    cache: true
  }
});
```

Comment: It works, thanks dude :D sorry for this question but i'm frustrated, i'm follow the instructions in select2 docs but found nothing and i don't know the query to serach in google